# problem with route in laravel return page not found

Tags: laravel, routes

i have this rout:

```
Route::get('/request_password', [ResetPasswordController::class, 'index'])->name('password.request');

Route::post('/request_password', [ResetPasswordController::class, 'sendEmail']);
```

and use it here:

```
 <div class="col">
            <!-- Simple link -->
            <a href="{{ route('password.request') }}">Forgot password?</a>
          </div>
```

the controller:

```
class ResetPasswordController extends Controller
{

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');

    }

    function index() {
        return view('auth.forget_password');
    }
```

and here the blade file in the (view/auth/forget_password.blade.php):

```
@extends('layout.app')
@section('title') Forget Password @endsection
@section('content')
@if(session()->has('msg'))
    <div class="alert alert-danger text-dark text-center m-3 p-3">{{ session('msg') }}</div>
@endif
<section class="h-100 bg-dark my-5">
    <div class="container py-5 h-100">
      <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center h-100">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="card card-registration my-4">
            <div class="row g-0">
              <div class="col-xl-6 d-none d-xl-block">
                <img src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/new-templates/bootstrap-registration/img4.webp"
                  alt="Sample photo" class="img-fluid"
                  style="border-top-left-radius: .25rem; border-bottom-left-radius: .25rem;" />
              </div>
              <div class="col-xl-6">
                <div class="card-body p-md-5 text-black">
                  <h3 class="mb-5 text-uppercase"> Forget Password</h3>

                 <form action="{{ route('password.request') }}" method="post">
```

the result in the browser:
[image]

I have already tried :

```
PHP artisan route:cache
PHP artisan cache:clear
```

Comment: what does `php artisan route:list` show for this route?

Comment: Your hyperlink to get route and your form are pointed to the same route "password.request". Why? is it a typo?

Comment: I just copy and paste everything from my other project where everything works correctly ?? route:list shows me everything correctly? I believe the problem not from code but something else !!!

Answer (score 0):

As @lagbox said, please check the route list with this command:
php artisan route:list
for any prefix and be sure about URL address